# Fill DataGridView in C# with Oracle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I am using C# asp.net, I have a class that return an `ArrayList` from the database. When the user presses a button on the page. So, is there is a way to fill it? Right now I am trying to find a datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example
Source : http://www.etechpulse.com/2012/10/bind-array-list-elements-to-grid-view.html

***Code Behind:***

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    BindGridview();
                }
            }

        // Single Dimensional array
        private void BindGridview()
        {
            string[] arrlist = // your function that gets the arraylist
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            // you need to do the following for each column
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrlist.Count(); i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[i]["Name"] = arrlist[i].ToString();
            }

            gvarray.DataSource = dt;  //gvarray is your GridView defined in aspx design
            gvarray.DataBind();
        }
```

Also do not forget to add  `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` if you want to fill the grid programmatically.